# Why does it say the wrong Message?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, minecraft

````
else if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'test2')) //you can change command name here - not recommended but you can :)
{
    message.reply('**Just a Test2**');
        fs.truncate('../ConsoleClient/Console/output.txt', 0, function(){});
            setTimeout(function () {
                var out = fs.readFileSync('../ConsoleClient/RaidAlerts/messages.txt', 'utf-8').toString();
                var out3 = "test2";
                if(out == "stone")
                {
                    out3 = "Walls are fine";
                }
                else if(out == "air")
                {
                    out3 = "**WEEWOO** We´re being raided **WEEWOO**";
                }
                else if(out == "other")
                {
                    out3 = "Someone changed the block. Check ASAP";
                }
                const outembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setColor(0xe580ff)
                .setTimestamp()
                .setTitle('Walls')
                .addField('Status', "```" + out3 + out + "```")
                .setURL("https://de.namemc.com/profile/Memag")
                message.channel.sendEmbed(outembed)
                fs.truncate('../ConsoleClient/Console/output.txt', 0, function(){});
            }, 1000);
}
````

Why does it say "Walls are finestoneother" or "Walls are finestoneair" or "Walls are finestonestone" instead of "Walls are fine", "**WEEWOO** We´re being raided **WEEWOO**" and "Someone changed the block. Check ASAP"?

Comment: The value of `out` is clearly `"other"` or `"stoneair"` or `"stonestone"` — `'Status', "```" + out3 + out + "```"` that concatenates `out3` with `out`

Comment: Don't include `out` in that expression? I have no idea what you're trying to achieve or why the code was written the way it is, but that's very likely the problem.

Comment: @Pointy The problem is that if `out` were one of those things, then the message should have started with "test2" or "Someone changed the block. Check ASAP", but it started with "Walls are fine" instead, despite `out` apparently not being `stone`.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica *should have started with "test2"* — how exactly? The `out3` variable is *initialized* to "test2" but it's later overwritten.

Comment: @Pointy Because "stonestone" and "stoneair" don't equal "stone", "air", or "other". And if it is "other", then it still should have started with "Someone changed the block. Check ASAP" and not with "Walls are fine".

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) for as long as it sees fit. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 1):

Try

````
.addField('Status', "```" + out3 + "```")
````

and post the content of "/ConsoleClient/RaidAlerts/messages.txt"

Comment: messages.txt is actually "empty" it just changes between "stone" "air" and "other" in there